# discord.py - my server info command doesn't reply

Tags: python, discord.py

This code is not giving an error also doesn't reply. I don't understand.

```py
@client.command()
 async def serverinfo(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{guild} sunucusunun bilgileri',description="Coded by Amazoen#1907",timestamp=ctx.message_created_at,color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Kanal Sayısı:",value=len(guild.channels))
    embed.add_field(name="Rol Sayısı:",value=len(guild.roles))
    embed.add_field(name="Booster Sayısı:",value=guild.premium_subscription_count)
    embed.add_field(name="Üye Sayısı:",value=guild.member_count)
    embed.add_field(name="Kuruluş Tarihi:",value=guild.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name="Sunucu Sahibi:",value=guild.owner)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Komut {ctx.author} tarafından kullanıldı.",icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: you added the @command.command(using cogs)/ @bot.command() right?

Comment: If your code is not working but also not giving any errors, always check if your command error handling might be "swallowing" the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following:

You use `ctx.message_created_at` instead of `ctx.message.created_at`.

- In the documentation you will see that the ctx object doesnt have a message_created_at field. Because this isnt known the program returns an error. (This was most likely a typo, so fixing it to `ctx.message.created_at` solves that part.)

The other problem is that you use `guild.icon` instead of `guild.icon_url`.

- The reason you need to use an url is that the embedded message cant handle images. It needs urls to images instead.

So fixing these two problems makes your code executable:

```
    async def serverinfo(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
        guild = ctx.guild
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{guild} sunucusunun bilgileri', description="Coded by Amazoen#1907",
                          timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Kanal Sayısı:", value=len(guild.channels))
        embed.add_field(name="Rol Sayısı:", value=len(guild.roles))
        embed.add_field(name="Booster Sayısı:", value=guild.premium_subscription_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Üye Sayısı:", value=guild.member_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Kuruluş Tarihi:", value=guild.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Sunucu Sahibi:", value=guild.owner)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Komut {ctx.author} tarafından kullanıldı.", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

---

But there is 1 extra thing that I would like to mention.

You use this line in the function input: `, guild: discord.Guild = None`.
Note that you later define a new variable with the same name "guild" `guild = ctx.guild`.

By doing this you dont use the variable created in the function input. Making the one defined in your function input useless.

I suggest updating it to this (as this does the same thing, and does is with less useless code):

```
    async def serverinfo(ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{guild} sunucusunun bilgileri', description="Coded by Amazoen#1907",
                          timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Kanal Sayısı:", value=len(guild.channels))
        embed.add_field(name="Rol Sayısı:", value=len(guild.roles))
        embed.add_field(name="Booster Sayısı:", value=guild.premium_subscription_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Üye Sayısı:", value=guild.member_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Kuruluş Tarihi:", value=guild.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Sunucu Sahibi:", value=guild.owner)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Komut {ctx.author} tarafından kullanıldı.", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**References:**

- [Message Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)
- [Guild Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild)
- [Context Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#context)
- [Embedded Messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)
- [set_thumbnail of embedded messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

These  were the things which were wrong in your code:

1. Instead of `ctx.guild`, you need to use `ctx.message.guild`.
2. Your way of using `len()` was not quite right.
3. Instead of using `guild.icon` you need to use `guild.icon_url`
   Here is how the final should look like -

```
@client.command()
async def testserverinfo(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    roles =[role for role in guild.roles]
    text_channels = [text_channels for text_channels in guild.text_channels]
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{guild.name} sunucusunun bilgileri', description="Coded by VideroDesigns.#9999", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
    embed.add_field(name="Kanal Sayısı:", value=f"{len(text_channels)}")
    embed.add_field(name="Rol Sayısı:", value=f"{len(roles)}")
    embed.add_field(name="Booster Sayısı:", value=guild.premium_subscription_count)
    embed.add_field(name="Üye Sayısı:", value=guild.member_count)
    embed.add_field(name="Kuruluş Tarihi:", value=guild.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name="Sunucu Sahibi:", value=guild.owner)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Komut {ctx.author} tarafından kullanıldı.", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: ctx.guild is valid. see documentation. And the fact he used ctx.message_created_at is also important as this also gives an error